# React hook form - Invalid hook call on useForm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am currently trying to unit test my application with jest and react testing library. I am getting an error from the useForm hook that is imported from React hook forms. I use the same hook in the same way in other components, but this is the only one that fails.
Here is the only test I have so far:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

describe("<App />", () => {
  test("smoke test", () => {
    render(<App />);
  });
});
```

And this is the error:

```js
 FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  <App />
    ✕ smoke test (119ms)

  ● <App /> › smoke test

    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   

      33 | 
      34 | export const SearchForm: React.FC<SearchProps> = (props) => {
    > 35 |   const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>();
         |                                      ^
      36 | 
      37 |   const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({ title, order }) => {
      38 |     fetch(`/api/movies/search/${title}?order=${order}`, {
```

Here is the component that errors on the useHook call

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import {
  Box,
  InputGroup,
  InputLeftElement,
  InputRightElement,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  Select,
  Icon,
} from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

interface Movies {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  picture_url: string;
  length: string;
  genres: string;
  avg: number;
  count: number;
}

interface SearchProps {
  onSearch: (movies: Movies[]) => void;
}

interface FormData {
  title: string;
  order: string;
}

export const SearchForm: React.FC<SearchProps> = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>();

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({ title, order }) => {
    fetch(`/api/movies/search/${title}?order=${order}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => props.onSearch(json))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });

  return (
    <Box pt="4" margin="auto" ml="5rem" mr="5.5rem">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <FormControl>
          <InputGroup size="md">
            <InputLeftElement
              children={<Icon name="search" color="gray.300" />}
            />
            <Input
              name="title"
              placeholder="Search IMDbest"
              type="text"
              ref={register}
            />
            <InputRightElement
              children={
                <Select onChange={onSubmit} name="order" ref={register}>
                  <option value="asc">Avg rating ascending</option>
                  <option value="desc">Avg rating descending</option>
                </Select>
              }
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

And here is the parent component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SearchForm } from "./forms/SearchForm";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Box, Image, Icon, SimpleGrid, Skeleton } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

interface Movies {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  picture_url: string;
  avg: number;
  genres: string;
  length: string;
  count: number;
}

export const MovieCards: React.FC = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movies[]>([]);


  const handleSubmit = (movies: Movies[]) => {
    setMovies(movies);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchForm onSearch={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
};
```

I have run `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom`, and have confirmed that only one instance of each library is in my project and they are both version `16.13.1`. I'm unsure how to proceed since the hook seems to be called correctly inside a functional component, and I also use the same hook in other components in the same way and they do not error.

Comment: Try do a clean install of your packages. While looking for problens like yours it seens to get it fixed sometimes. A example https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/59

Comment: I had react-hook-form installed in the wrong package.json!